# Reduce function returns error

Tags: inequalities

I am trying to prove the inequality below for the given condition stated, but I get a warning result.

`Reduce[((1 + x^2)^0.5) <= (1 + x + 2 Abs[y]) && x >= y]`

`Reduce: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.`

Then it gives me this:  `y\[Element] Reals && x >= y`
So does it mean it just agrees with it? Can I make it show steps as to why?

How do I resolve the above issue? Or get Mathematica to prove that for me for all Real numbers? Can I also have it plot each side so I can also visually see that is always true?

Comment: It means your original system is equivalent to `x >= y` (both variables being real). The warning message warns you of a slight boo-boo in writing `(1 + x^2)^0.5` instead of `(1 + x^2)^(1/2)`. `Reduce` is an exactly solver that expects exact input free of approximate floating-point numbers like `0.5`. (All floating-point numbers are treated as approximate.) Adding the domain `Reals` removes the extraneous condition: `Reduce[((1 + x^2)^0.5) <= (1 + x + 2 Abs[y]) && x >= y, {}, Reals]`. Finally, `Reduce` does not show its steps, which you can derive by squaring both sides and some algebra.

Comment: `Reduce[((1 + x^2)^0.5) <= (1 + x + 2 Abs[y]) && x >= y // 
  Rationalize, Reals]`

Comment: Thanks both! So I cannot use Mathematica to show any proof or steps then. I am sure it goes through an internal logic to get to that conclusion. No way to turn on a switch to show the steps of that logic? Also: is there another notation to enter sqrt() instead of ^(1/2). and btw, when I say ^0.5 I mean ^0.5 and not ^0.500000001 why would it even care.

Comment: `Trace[Reduce[...], TraceInternal -> True]` will show some of the evaluation sequence, but it might not show all of it. I doubt it will be easy to follow. Algorithms do a lot things humans wouldn’t do in ways that humans wouldn’t do.

Comment: Yeah tried it. Nothing useful. It even practically repeated the original sequence, literally nothing added! But note I manually proved it by hand just now.